# Passing around parsed arguments makes no fun

Tags: python, design-patterns, argparse

I use [arparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) in Python to parse arguments from the command line:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=usage)
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument(...)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

I use object `args` only in few places of the code.

There are three methods and the call stack looks like this

```
def first_level(args):
    second_level()

def second_level():
    third_level()

def third_level():
    ### here I want to add some logging if args.verbose is True
```

I want to add some logging to `third_level()`.

I don't like to change the signature of the method `second_level()`.

How can I make the `arg` object available in `third_lelvel()`?

I could store `arg` as global variable, but I was told to not use global variables in a developer training some years ago ....

What is common way to handle this?

Comment: Dont condition the logging in your `third_level(..)`. Use `if args.verbose: logging.setLevel(logging.INFO)` instead.

Comment: I would only ever pass the `args` object to the first function. If the others need values from it, I would pass them in as values in the function signature, to make it clear what they need. Call them as `second_level(verbose=args.verbose)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer. I'd suggest not condition in your `third_level(..)` at all. There are mechanisms to let the logging module take care of that -- and those mechanisms can be controlled from outside of those 3 functions.

Something like:

```
def first_level(args):
    second_level()

def second_level():
    third_level()

def third_level():
    logging.info("log line which will be printed if logging is at INFO level")


def main():
    args = ....
    #Set the logging level, conditionally
    if args.verbose:
        logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.WARNING)

    first_level(args)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. For this case, using logging is best. If the access to args.foo is for different purpose, then a different solution is needed. But this is a different question...

Comment: I'll probably wrap the three functions in a class (if it is meaningful), and set the variable within the object, the third function can use it as: `self.variable`

Answer (score 2):

A common module structure is something like:

```
 imports ...
 <constants>
 options = {verbose=0, etc}
 # alt options = argparse.Namespace(logging=False,....)

 def levelone(args, **kwargs):
     ....
 def leveltwo(...):

 def levelthree(...):
     <use constant>
     <use options>

 def parser():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ....
    args = p.parse_args()  # this uses sys.argv

 if __name__=='__main__':
      args = parser()
      options.update(vars(args))
      levelone(args)
```

The body of the module has function definitions, and can be imported by another module. If used as a script then `parser` reads the commandline.  That global `options` is available for all sorts of `state` like parameters.  In sense they are are constants that the user, or importing module, can tweak.  Values imported from a `config` file can have the same role.

Another common pattern is to make your functions methods of a class, and pass `args` as object attributes.

```
class Foo():
   def __init__(self, logging=False):
      self.logging = logging
   def levelone():
   def leveltwo():
      <use self.logging>
foo(args.logging).levelone()
```

While `globals` are discouraged, it's more because they get overused, and spoil the modularity that functions provide.  But Python also provides a `module` level namespace that can contain more than just functions and classes.  And any function defined in the module can access that namespace - unless its own definitions shadow it.

```
 var1 = 'module level variable'
 var2 = 'another'
 def foo(var3):
    x = var1  # read/use var1
    var2 = 1   # shadow the module level definition
    etc
```

================

I'm not sure I should recommend this or not, but you could parse `sys.argv` within `third_level`.

```
 def third_level():
     import argparse
     p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     p.add_argument('-v','--verbose',action='count')
     args = p.parse_known_args()
     verbose = args.verbose
     <logging>
```

`argparse` imports `sys` and uses `sys.argv`.  It can do that regardless of whether it is use at your script level, in your `main` or some nested function.  `logging` does the same sort of thing.  You could use your own imported module to covertly pass values into functions.  Obviously that can be abused.  A `class` with class attributes can also be used this way.